# Best practice of structuring data in a vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have several views in my vue project. Some of these have the same component in them which will display the same data. At the moment I am getting the data in the components when they are mounted. Should I be getting the data higher up so it is only fetched once if it is the same to minimise requests? I’m not sure what is best practice for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not fond of any store/global state management.
They are just singletons for me. In ESM a module is *kinda* a singleton, so put your data in a module and use it in any place you want :)

data.js:

```
import {reactive} from 'vue'
import api from './api.js'

let loadingPromise;
const data = reactive({
   // enter some default values to display or mark it as not loaded
   loaded: false
})

export function loadData(){
    // start loading data when first demanded
    loadingPromise ??= api.get('my-endpoint')
    // this will update your components reactively
    .then(responseData => Object.assign(data, responseData, {loaded: true})) 
    
    return data; // just return the reactive data even if it's not loaded yet

}
```

Component.vue

```
<script setup>

import {loadData} from './data.js'

const data = loadData()

</script>
<template>
<div v-if="!data.loaded">Not loaded yet...</div>
<div v-else>
<!-- display your component content here -->
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the benefit of this over loading it in the root app.vue and just making it available to any views and components through props?

Comment: @jord49 The most established design patterns / architectures advocate splitting your presentation (UI) and data (business logic). In my example the data is reusable accross the whole application. The more complex an app the more places you would want to inject some data into. So placing all of your data separately from components would benefit in a long term and give you a freedom to use your reactive data in any place you want. Component should be dumb as much as possible, they should only present the data to the user, not caring about managing your data. Leave it for service modules

Comment: Makes a lot of sense thank you, I’ll do that.